# How to get CameraMetadata from preview in Nexus 5 using camera2 api

Tags: android, android-camera2, nexus-5

When all `AF, AE, AWB` control modes are set `AUTO`, I am trying to get current capture result's focus distance, exposure time, iso and color correction gains  using camera2 as below:

```
lensFocusDistance = result.get(CaptureResult.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE);
ccGains = result.get(CaptureResult.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS);
exposureTime = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME);
iso = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY);
```

The `result` is from `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback`'s `onCaptureCompleted`.
It works fine on Samsung series, even Google Pixel, but not Nexus 5 (probably Nexus 5x too). on Nexus 5, all returns `null`. I am not sure what I am missing or it is Nexus issue.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.